# mysqli - mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my class code:

```
class DAL
{

public function paramtypez($val)
{
        $types = '';                        //initial sting with types
        foreach($val as $para) 
        {     
            if(is_int($para)) {
                $types .= 'i';              //integer
            } elseif (is_float($para)) {
                $types .= 'd';              //double
            } elseif (is_string($para)) {
                $types .= 's';              //string
            } else {
                $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
            }
        }
        return $types;
}

 public function execsql($query,$param)
{
    $conn=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","sample");

    if($row=$conn->prepare($query))
    {
        array_unshift($param,array(DAL::paramtypez($param)));
        call_user_func_array(array($row, 'bind_param'), $param);

        $row->execute();
        return true;
    }
    else
    return false;

}
}
```

and is use this class like this:

```
$vars = new DAL();
$vars->execsql('insert into tesst (name,family,age) values(?,?,?)',array('mori','gre','25'));
```

but that's return me this error:

```
 Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in ..\htdocs\inc.php on line 30
```

how can fix this error?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$param` looks like this right before you pass it to call_user_func_array:

```
[['ssi'],'mori','gre','25']
```

This is incorrect. You should change this:

```
array_unshift($param,array(DAL::paramtypez($param)));
```

To this:

```
array_unshift($param,DAL::paramtypez($param));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are giving an array when [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) expects an actual reference:

Try and see if this works:

```
class DAL
{

    public function paramtypez($val)
    {
            $types = '';                        //initial sting with types
            foreach($val as $para) 
            {     
                if(is_int($para)) {
                    $types .= 'i';              //integer
                } elseif (is_float($para)) {
                    $types .= 'd';              //double
                } elseif (is_string($para)) {
                    $types .= 's';              //string
                } else {
                    $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
                }
            }
            return $types;
    }

    public function execsql($query,$param)
    {

        $conn=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","sample");

        if($row=$conn->prepare($query))
        {
            array_unshift($param,array(DAL::paramtypez($param)));
            call_user_func_array(array($row, 'bind_param'), $this->makeValuesReferenced($param));

            $row->execute();
            return true;
        }
        else
        return false;

    }


    protected function makeValuesReferenced(&$arr)
    {
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but ...  Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in inc.php on line 31.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96770